VScode, ищу форматтер для django-html
Подключаюсь через vscode к удаленному серверу и открываю проект на django
ищу расширение для vscode, которое форматирует templates, которые соотносятся с django-html
Попробовал 2 расширения

djLint monosans, не могу заставить работать на удаленной машине. В локальном окружении все хорошо работает
Django Template Support, выкидывает много ошибок, которые я исправить никак не могу. Например,

подчеркивает тэги <br> как не закрытые,
показывает необходимость использования кавычек, где я их ставить не хочу
и тд и тп



Кто подскажет хорошее расширение, ну или хотя бы то, которое можно лекго кастомизировать и убрать не нужные правила из коробки
